# Switch/Select statement: is it possible to jump to a different case clause?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Say I have this in VB.NET:

```
Dim executeB As Boolean
Select Case myVariable
  Case "a"
    'some code
  Case "b"
     'some code
  Case Else
End Select
```

If myVariable is "a", control will go into the first case statement.  Now let's say if myVariable = "a", but inside a's case block, I find that executeB is true, is it then possible to jump to the second case?

Comment: Why do you have c# in your tag list, if you're looking for VB code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET Switch Statement GoTo Case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820104/vb-net-switch-statement-goto-case)

Comment: @Jon...I just chose to cite the example in VB.NET, but I was interested in knowing the answer for both C# and VB.NET (that's why I titled the question "Switch/Select".

Comment: It's worth being clear about this sort of thing in the question, in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, encapsulate the code within the `"b"` case into a function/procedure and call it from case `"a"`

Comment: That's what I'd normally do, but I wanted to see if the framework allows you to go from one case to another.

Comment: @Prabhu I understand. The other alternative is the GOTO which most programming languages support, including VB.NET. I don't really like the idea, that's why I didn't propose it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to jump from case A to case B, then a switch probably isn't the correct thing to be using. The switch structure is based on the idea that each path is mutually exclusive.

But to answer the actual question, no I'm pretty sure you can't jump into a case.

Comment: Thanks, that's really what I wanted to know.  In that case, I probably have to refactor as @lcarus suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [GoTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69whc95c.aspx) statement. That said, you shouldn't, it's almost never the right thing to do and I can't remember an instance where it actually would make code clearer as opposed to `break`, `continue` and `return`, its more structured cousins. (Or as opposed to breaking up the code so neither is necessary.) Wrap the switch case bodies in functions and just call those.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I you may want to make whatever "executeB" is into a private function and just call that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, in general what you're trying to do is bad, it's called waterfalling.  .Net tries to prevent you from doing it, because it introduces hard to troubleshoot bugs into your code.  If you trully have compound conditions you'd want to use a normal if/then/else.

Comment: I wouldn't normally do this, but I'm working on someone else's code and need to find a way to modify something without refactoring too much.