# Jump from Cases in the same switch vb.net

Tags: vb.net, select-case

I am building a game and I need to jump from Case to another. For example if the player is in the box 5 then the avatar needs to move to the box 9. Any help is highly appreciated.`

```
            Case 5
                OBJETO_ATERIOR = R4
                OBJETO_ACTUAL = R5
                OBJETO_ANTERIOR_INVERSO = R6

                'needs to jumpo to Case 9


                gif_loro.Visible = False
                gif_puppy.Visible = False
                gif_mono.Visible = False
                gif_oca5.Visible = True`
```

Comment: this could be a duplicate of this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820104/vb-net-switch-statement-goto-case

Comment: You could put your logic in different method and call the method based on the cases. Saying "move to box 9" is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take the time to read about [mcve]. As it stands, the code you supplied seems to have nothing useful to do with your question.

Though guessing at an answer, you could extract the code in the `Case 9` block out into it's own Sub, and call that from the `Case 9` block and from the appropriate point in the `Case 5` block. An inelegant solution, but it may be your only choice.

So looking at an example, lets say your code looks something like this

```
Select Case x
    Case 1
        'case 1 code
    Case 2
        'case 2 code
    Case 3
        'case 3 code
    Case 4
        'case 4 code
    Case 5
        'case 5 code
        'jump to case 9 code
    Case 6
        'case 6 code
    Case 7
        'case 7 code
    Case 8
        'case 8 code
    Case 9
        'case 9 code
End Select.
```

You could create a sub that contains your code in the `Case 9` block like so

```
 Private Sub Case9Code()
    'case 9 code
End Sub
```

and now you can rewrite your `Select Case` block as ..

```
Select Case x
    Case 1
        'case 1 code
    Case 2
        'case 2 code
    Case 3
        'case 3 code
    Case 4
        'case 4 code
    Case 5
        'case 5 code
        Case9Code()
    Case 6
        'case 6 code
    Case 7
        'case 7 code
    Case 8
        'case 8 code
    Case 9
        Case9Code()
End Select.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting what you are asking what you want is something like a `goto` statement (not available in VB.NET). This also indicates poor design and in turn I can offer an idea for a refactor.

The player object could contain a `move` sub that is called when moving spaces. This `move` could raise an event as well. The avatar object could contain a `moveListener` sub that listens for the move event to be raised and has a switch statement to determine how to handle the avatar movement. Since VB.NET events can contain params, the space the player moved to could be contained in the parameter; thus yielding an event handling design where the player movement is seen as an event and the avatar *reacts* to it.